# View scoped JSF bean is used in multiple tabs

Tags: jsf

I have a simple example in which a JSF bean with view scope is called from different browser tabs

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:autoComplete value="#{testBean.item}"
                            dropdown="true"
                            completeMethod="#{testBean.completeItems}"
                            var="item"
                            itemLabel="#{item}"
                            itemValue="#{item}" />

            <p:commandButton value="submit" update="selectedValue" />

            <p:outputLabel id="selectedValue" value="Selected item: #{testBean.item}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private String item;

    private final List<String> items = Arrays
            .asList("item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9");

    public List<String> completeItems(final String query) {
        return items.stream()
                .filter(i -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(i, query))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

When I open the same page in a different browser tab, after selecting a value, I see the selected value from the other tab. I thought a view scoped bean would be created for each browser tab.

I am using Spring Boot v2.5.6, Glassfisch Jakarta Faces v2.3.17 and PrimeFaces v11.0.0

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you probably missmatch JSF beans <> CDI beans <> Spring beans - 

you currently use CDI annotations but dont have a CDI implementation, therefore propably your TestBean is a Spring singleton scoped bean. 

Check JoinFaces or use another container like Quarkus, Meecrowave, ...

Comment: I added JoinFaces and everything works fine. Thank you very much!